How do I trigger a ZeroMQ zmq.EVENT_HANDSHAKE_FAILED_PROTOCOL error?
I am testing an event monitor I wrote in Python for ZeroMQ. I would like to test my callback for the zmq.EVENT_HANDSHAKE_FAILED_PROTOCOL event. What is the easiest way to trigger this event? The reason it triggers or value does not matter; I just need to get it to trigger so I could see if my logic works.

I think you could get something like what you want by having a peer connect (or bind) with a raw tcp socket and not a ZMQ socket, and have it send random data.
The event you're looking to generate is raised in response to the ZMQ socket you're monitoring not understanding what's been sent to it (i.e. something's gone wrong in the handling of bytes that are supposed to be zmtp PDUs), so sending random data is highly like to result in the zmq socket get very confused as to what's going on.
The other way would be to cook up a specially broken version of the ZMQ library. That's probably harder to accomplish.
==EDIT==
According to Jason, that didn't work.
Thumbing through the source code, the event is associated with mismatches or problems with cryptography or authentication settings. So, if one peer has set the ZMQ_PLAIN_SERVER socket option, and the other hasn't, there is a mismatch. That should result in with a HANDSHAKE_FAILED_PROTOCOL with a error code of ZMQ_PROTOCOL_ERROR_ZMTP_MECHANISM_MISMATCH. The source code that causes this is within the zmq::zmtp_engine_t::handshake_v3_x() method in the file zmtp_engine.cpp in the source code for libzmq.
Looking at the occurences of this event being raised, it's always associated in some way with encryption / authentication mechanisms that zmq_sockets can be set to use through zmq_setsockopt().

Thanks. I'll try your first suggestion and let you know. I had considered mocking part of the ZMQ library but i am not sure how to do that with events or even if it is possible.

No dice. It did not work.

@jasonsf oh dang. Ok, I’ve got used to rummaging through zmq’s source code and I’ll see what should cause it.

@jasonsf, Ok, I've looked through the source code, and edited my answer. It's raised when there's a problem or mismatch in encryption / authentication options for sockets, so I suggest having two peers that are deliberately mismatched in how they're configured.

@jasonsf Also, the test code in the source for libzmq has examples that generate this event - look at files like test_security_curve.cpp in the source for libzmq, and functions like test_curve_security_invalid_hello_command_name(). That is like what I first suggested, with the addition of the socket being tested being set for curve security, and sending an 'X' through the BSD socket to the zmq socket to cause the initial handshaking to go wrong (it's expecting '\0x05HELLO`).
